# Copy all files except those already present

Tags: linux, file-transfer, copy

So my problem is I have to move a folder with 120k files from a to b via c. (As a and b are not on the same system, but c is available to both)
The systems are debian-based.

However c is limited in disk size, so I couldn't copy the whole folder in one go.
It copied about 98k files before it couldn't copy anymore.

So I have cleaned c up again. I have all 120k files in a and 98k files already in b.
How do I copy just the remaining 22k files?

Comment: please change your comment to an answer... it could help others.